# Cytoscape.js - draw edges below compound node

Tags: javascript, css, cytoscape.js

I have a set of nodes grouped inside a parent (compound) node. I would like to display the edges from the "outer" nodes (those outside the compound node) to the "inner" nodes (those inside the compound node) **below** the compound node.

(Approximately like [this demo](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/cose-bilkent-layout-compound/).)

Thus far, I've tried setting the `z-index` property like this, with `z-index-compare` set to `manual`, but it doesn't work:

```
style: [
    {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
            'z-index-compare': 'manual',
            'width': 10,
            'height': 10,
            'background-color': '#46A',
            'z-index': 3
        }
    },
    {
        selector: ':parent',
        style: {
            'z-index-compare': 'manual',
            'background-color': '#CDF',
            'z-index': 9
        }
    },
    {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
            'z-index-compare': 'manual',
            'width': 1,
            'line-color': '#BCE',
            'z-index': 1
        }
    },
    {
        selector: '.dense',
        style: {
            'z-index-compare': 'manual',
            'width': 0.5,
            'z-index': 1
        }
    }
]
```

The documentation for Cytoscape.js says nothing about where to specify the `z-index-compare` property, so maybe there's an error in my CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution I found was to remove the `z-index` tags and use `z-compound-depth` on the `:parent` selector, like this:

```
style: [
    {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
            'width': 10,
            'height': 10,
            'background-color': '#46A'
        }
    },
    {
        selector: ':parent',
        style: {
            'z-compound-depth': 'top',
            'background-color': '#CDF'
        }
    },
    {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
            'width': 1,
            'line-color': '#BCE'
        }
    },
    {
        selector: '.dense',
        style: {
            'width': 0.5
        }
    }
]
```